# How to name variables with numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the right convention in Ruby to name the variables if the number is the last character?

`my_awesome_variable_1`
or
`my_awesome_variable1`

`a_1`
or
`a1`

`firs_1?`
or
`firs1?`

`foo_1_000_000`
or
`foo1000000`

---

Sub-question: what about acronyms?

- for variables

`foo_RTFM`
or
`foo_rtfm`

- and for classes/moudles

`FooRTFM`
or
`FooRtfm`

EDIT: it looks like there is no such a convention in Ruby, so let me ask you what you use.

`a_1` / `a1`

Comment: Hmm, seems rather opinion-based... There is however an excellent guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: that guide is awesome i always use!!! answer your question  use snake_case for symbols, methods and variables, in your case my_awesome_variable_1 its the right way

Comment: I would argue that your variable names shouldn't have numbers in them in the first place.

Comment: Honest question: what's the use case for variable names with numbers in them?

Comment: ..the lack of fantasy, foo, bar, baz, then what.. foo1 :] ok, that's a valid point, that perhaps the numbers shouldn't be there at all

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't use numbers in variable names.

If you have multiple `thing`s, simply use an Array:

```
thing = []
thing << "foo"
thing << "bar"
# or
thing = ["foo", "bar"]
```

---

While Ruby doesn't provide you with a strict style guide like Go does, there is [an excellent Style Guide by Bozhidar Batsov](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

To answer most of your question:

> Use snake_case for symbols, methods and variables

and

> Use CamelCase for classes and modules. (**Keep acronyms like HTTP, RFC, XML uppercase**.)

(This CAN lead to problems if you work with rails, but [there is a simple solution](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym).)

Comment: Why should one not keep acronyms upper case? Yes, that's why i wrote "*most* of your question"

Comment: To be honest I think the question should be closed because it is "mostly opinion-based".

Comment: Rails at one point had serious problems auto-loading classes and modules that contained names like `FooHTTP` instead of `FooHttp`. I'm not sure if that's actually still a problem, but regardless the question was specifically about `a_1` vs `a1`, which you've ignored completely.  You haven't answer "most" of the question, you've answered a tiny *aside* in the question.

Comment: Exactly, I didn't got the answers yet, all I got is a down vote and a hint, that my question should be closed. I came from different language (Java) where it's not question of style, well the acronyms probably are. I am noob so I ask.

Comment: oh, and that guide on GitHub is awesome, thx